# How to display exactly 10 lines of a command output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I am working on ARM-based processor and I am preparing inside it a shell script that writes into a text file a set of commands output.

I want it to write exactly 10 lines of a command's output (for example top command) but I don't know how, would you help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: I did not provide code because I am asking a linux command question, no code is needed, thank you.

Comment: Clear, I did not know that, I will be specific next time

Comment: No problems. In the future the easiest way to avoid unwanted attention is to provide some of your code, even if it is not working. I find the easiest way is to `cat` a 3 or 4 line bash script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which operating system are you working in ? If you have `awk` installed, you
can do:

```
command | awk 'NR<=10' > f.txt
```

Comment: OS: Linux version 3.4.35
thank you , the device supports awk command and it works

Answer (score 6):

```
command | head -n 10 > file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, the ARM processor I'm working  with does not support head command, is there any alternatives ?

Comment: `command | sed 10q > file.txt` should do the same. If you don't have `sed` either, I guess you could do a while loop: `i=0 ; command | while read line ; do echo $line ; ((i++)) ; test $i -ge 10 && break ; done`

Comment: sed command is not supported, thanks for your advice, but I found simpler solution with awk command

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pure Bash solution:

```
n=0
command | while (( n++ != 10 )) && IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I found the solution with awk command

Answer (score -1):

`command | sed 1,10p > f.txt`

`sed` filters lines based on a pattern and performs an action on them. In this case,  pattern is to filter lines whose number is between 1 and 10, and action is just to 'p'rint them.

Comment: thanks for helping, sed is not supported in the processor i'm working with, I found the solution with awk command

Comment: Hi @DebanjanB, I validated an answer that solved my issue and I answered all other answers.